# Mysql error slave does not connect to master db

Tags: mysql

I'm setting up a replica, made every configuration as I should. but when I run `show slave status;`, I get the result below

```
+----------------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------------------+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Slave_IO_State       | Master_Host    | Master_User    | Master_Port | Connect_Retry | Master_Log_File  | Read_Master_Log_Pos | Relay_Log_File         | Relay_Log_Pos | Relay_Master_Log_File | Slave_IO_Running | Slave_SQL_Running | Replicate_Do_DB | Replicate_Ignore_DB | Replicate_Do_Table | Replicate_Ignore_Table | Replicate_Wild_Do_Table | Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table | Last_Errno | Last_Error | Skip_Counter | Exec_Master_Log_Pos | Relay_Log_Space | Until_Condition | Until_Log_File | Until_Log_Pos | Master_SSL_Allowed | Master_SSL_CA_File | Master_SSL_CA_Path | Master_SSL_Cert | Master_SSL_Cipher | Master_SSL_Key | Seconds_Behind_Master | Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert | Last_IO_Errno | Last_IO_Error                                                                                 | Last_SQL_Errno | Last_SQL_Error | Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids | Master_Server_Id | Master_UUID | Master_Info_File           | SQL_Delay | SQL_Remaining_Delay | Slave_SQL_Running_State                                | Master_Retry_Count | Master_Bind | Last_IO_Error_Timestamp | Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp | Master_SSL_Crl | Master_SSL_Crlpath | Retrieved_Gtid_Set | Executed_Gtid_Set | Auto_Position | Replicate_Rewrite_DB | Channel_Name | Master_TLS_Version |
+----------------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------------------+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Connecting to master | master-ip | holberton_user |        3306 |            60 | mysql-bin.000001 |                 154 | mysql-relay-bin.000005 |             4 | mysql-bin.000001      | Connecting       | Yes               |                 |                     |                    |                        |                         |                             |          0 |            |            0 |                 154 |             154 | None            |                |             0 | No                 |                    |                    |                 |                   |                |                  NULL | No                            |          1045 | error connecting to master 'holberton_user@master-ip:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 48 |              0 |                |                             |                0 |             | /var/lib/mysql/master.info |         0 |                NULL | Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates |              86400 |             | 210911 11:14:59         |                          |                |                    |                    |                   |             0 |                      |              |                    |
+----------------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------------------+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

What I did on the master:

- `sudo ufw allow from replica_server_ip to any port 3306`
- `sudo emacs /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
- `#bind-address            = 127.0.0.1` (the commenting was a requirement)
- `server-id               = 1`
- `binlog_do_db          = tyrell_corp`

I also created a MySQL user and gave it the necessary permissions.

What I did on the slave:

- `mysql -u root -p`
- `CREATE DATABASE tyrell_corp;`
- `sudo mysql -u root -p tyrell_corp < /tmp/tyrell_corp.sql`

Slave configuration file:

- `sudo emacs /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
- `server-id               = 2`
- `log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log`
- `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
- `binlog_do_db            = tyrell_corp`
- `relay-log               = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log`
  Then restart Mysql.

In the slave MYSQL console I did:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST='master-ip',
MASTER_USER='holberton_user',
MASTER_PASSWORD='projectcorrection280hbtn',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
MASTER_LOG_POS=154;
```

NB *master-ip* is the ip of my master address.

Comment: This question is about database administration and not about programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The dba sister site of SO deals with such questions

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that I shouldn't ask about db here,  sorry. Which one is the sister site please?